# How to send query param in google login url and use that in callback method

Tags: authentication, nestjs, google-oauth, passport.js

I am using google authentication in my project. And I want to send query param in the URL that hit the google authentication and use that param in callback method that are hit by callbackurl.
Its a NEST-JS application.

**Controller**

```
@Get('google/login')
  @UseGuards(GoogleAuthGaurd)
  handleGoogleLogin() {}

  @Get('google/redirect')
  @UseGuards(GoogleAuthGaurd)
  async handleGoogleRedirect(@Req() req, @Res() res: Response) {
    const tokens = await this.authService.signInWithGoogle(req);
    res.redirect(
      302,localhost:8080?tokens=token);
  }
```

**Google Guard**

```
@Injectable()
export class GoogleAuthGaurd extends AuthGuard('google') {}
```

Strategy

```
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      clientID: configService.get(ConfigEnum.CLIENT_ID),
      clientSecret: configService.get(ConfigEnum.CLIENT_SECRET),
      callbackURL: configService.get('CALLBACK_URL'),
      scope: ['profile', 'email'],
    });
  }
  async validate(
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    profile: Profile,
    done: VerifiedCallback,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const email = profile.emails[0].value;
    done(null, email);
  }
}
```

I tried to get the query param in my handleGoogleLogin method but it directly went to the strategy class

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add query params in the guard using the ExecutionContext. It works but it does not appear in the callback url.